# SQL Query count row of same id in a different table

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Already checked other answers but unfortunately didn't help me. So im hoping to count how many same id from different table. This is how my tables look like

[image]

The first table from the left is "resources" and the second is "equipment_entity". So I want to count how many `resource_class_id` is there when joined with `equipment_entity.id`. This is what I've tried so far but doesn't work. Any help would do. Link with same problem or any help. Thanks ahead!

```
SELECT e.*, r.equipment_class_id, r.resource_type FROM equipment_entity as e LEFT JOIN resources as r ON e.id = r.equipment_class_id COUNT(DISTINCT r.equipment_class_id) where r.resource_type = 'equipment'
```

and also, im having this error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'COUNT(DISTINCT r.equipment_class_id) where r.resource_type =
>   'equipment' LIMIT 0' at line 1

Comment: Would you be so kind as to set up a fiddle with a sample of your data so that I (or somebody else) may play with it?

Comment: @hd1 okay sir one moment

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4062c/1 try this sir @hd1

Comment: Now update your question to show what you want to get?

Comment: "So I want to count how many resource_class_id is there when joined with equipment_entity.id".  I don't quite follow what this means.  Further, your sample data has `resource_class` but your query refers to `resource_type`.  Confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following query. This will give you all the Rows from equipment_entity Table and the count of rows in resource table for each equipment.

```
SELECT e.*, count(*) AS count FROM `equipment_entity` AS e left join `resources` AS r ON e.id = r.equipment_class_id GROUP BY e.id
```

Comment: @Anthony.Jay Could you please accept the answer as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options. You you are decided that you wants to know the count for r.resource_type = 'equipment', then the first query will work for you.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT r.equipment_class_id)
FROM equipment_entity AS e
     LEFT JOIN resources AS r ON e.id = r.equipment_class_id
WHERE r.resource_type = 'equipment';
```

But if you wants to see all resource_type's count in one go, you can use GROUP BY as below to get your desired results.

```
SELECT r.equipment_class_id,
COUNT(DISTINCT r.equipment_class_id)
FROM equipment_entity AS e
     LEFT JOIN resources AS r ON e.id = r.equipment_class_id
GROUP BY r.equipment_class_id;
```

Comment: Ohh... taken from your posted query :) Search the column "equipment_class_id" actually exists in table "resources" or not!!

Comment: its actually resource_class_id. did change it tho when i tried it but didnt get the result i was looking for. but still big thanks! the query by @user1309690 was the result im expecting

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
SELECT r.equipment_class_id, r.resource_type, count(r.equipment_class_id) count 
FROM equipment_entity as e LEFT JOIN resources as r 
ON e.id = r.equipment_class_id  where r.resource_type = 'equipment' GROUP BY equipment_class_id
```

Answer (score 0):

> So I want to count how many resource_class_id is there when joined with equipment_entity.id

I don't quite follow that this means.  Two interpretations are below.

Based on your data model, the table `resources` seems to have at least two columns `id` and `resource_class`.  The table `equipment_entity` seems to have `resource_class_id`.  I have adjusted this answer to reflect these names.

If you want to count the number of equipment that have a particular resource type, then just use `JOIN` and `COUNT`():

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM equipment_entity  e JOIN
     resources r
     ON r.id = e.resource_class_id
WHERE r.resource_class = 'equipment';
```

Neither `COUNT(DISTINCT)` nor a `LEFT JOIN` are needed.

If you want to count *all* resource classes, then:

```
SELECT r.resource_class, COUNT(e.id)
FROM resources r JOIN
     equipment_entity e
     ON r.id = e.resource_class_id
GROUP BY r.resource_class;
```